# How to change style of title of Content Dialog in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How to change style of `title` property of `ContentDialog` page in Windows Phone 8.1.

XAML:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="MyApp.View.Login.ContentDialog1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.View.Login"
    Title="DIALOG TITLE">

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Name="email" Header="Email address"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Here we have `Title="DIALOG TITLE"`, can I change style of text show in `title`?

**EDIT**

[image]

How to reduce top most empty space in `ContentDialog` if `title` not mention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title will show in the ContentDialog's [TitleTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.titletemplate.aspx). You can change that as needed.

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="MyApp.View.Login.ContentDialog1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.View.Login"
    Title="DIALOG TITLE">

    <ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- what do you want the title to look like -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Name="email" Header="Email address"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: Can I change default height of ContentDialog from top if window dont have any title? looks like by default 50 margin from top occupied by title or windows default. Check edited question.

Comment: I unable to add  X button  at right corner of Contentdialog. I put there two column grid but not work. Can you help me ?

Comment: I just want to mention, that in order to use the standard Title value in this case, you'd have to add the following line inside the template: Text="{Binding}"